# unexpected token in css external file

Tags: html, css

I'm very beginner to HTML and CSS. I tried to add css with my external file. But It's the error as unexpected token. Please find the error in image file. My code is as like below.

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Test Game</title>
<script src="C:\Users\Pspl\Desktop\Sreekanth\TestGame.css"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div class='dvborder'>dsfssd</div>
</body>
</html>
```

css file code :

```
body {
background-color: lightblue;
}
```

[image: Error message as like this image]

Comment: please add the complete css

Comment: use link not script

Comment: Yes, used. but the css is not effecting.

Comment: First google it

Comment: why -1 for my problem ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You must use `<link>` instead of `<script>`.

`<link>` - is for embedding external CSS file while
`<script>` - is for embedding external JS file

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="C:\Users\Pspl\Desktop\Sreekanth\TestGame.css">
```

Comment: Hard-coding a local file is plain wrong. He will move the website to some domain and nothing will work anymore. If he makes a mistake, don't propagate it. Please take time to explain.

Comment: Yes exactly. I just give a view not to use script for CSS file. It's a bad practice to hard coded file path. Specify relative path like "../../TestGame.css"

Answer (score 2):

Use [`<script>`](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_script.asp) for `.js` files and [`<link>`](http://www.w3schools.com/Tags/tag_link.asp) for `.css` files.

Comment: Yess, thank you. error gone. But css not effected. Can you check that too please.

Comment: The `unexpected token` was because it expected `JavaScript` and you gave it `css`. But you say that's fixed. Do you still have an error? What does the new error say?

Answer (score 1):

That's simply not at all how you [link to css](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/HTML/Element/link). The syntax for style sheets is

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="(URL of your .css)" />
```

The browser is expecting a javascript file, and complaining that CSS doesn't look like javascript.

Answer (score 1):

Try link tag instead of script tag.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="theme.css">
```

Answer (score 0):

> ```
> <link>  tag is used to relate stylesheets or linked documents.
> <script> is used to embed  an executable script within an HTML.
> ```

If you are having local files, try to use relative path for stylesheets and script files. This improve portability.